# Differences Between Textmate 1.5 and Sublime Text 2 for Ruby on Rails Development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, textmate, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I recently switched to a Mac. I am trying to choose between Textmate 1.5 and Sublime Text 2 for Ruby on Rails development. I know these editors have a great deal in common from my own testing. I don't however see many differences as of yet. If you have experiance with both, can you please make a list of the differences between the two?

Please make any list without subjective comments as I'm not looking to start a flame war; only factual differences. There are many resources that list similarities -- please focus on the differences.

Thank you.

Comment: I switched to S2 because T crashed when opening big files or duing search.

Comment: I'm using textmate (got already a license), but I've also tried sublime2, and it looks good. You also have some useful tools that you can use, same as textmate (git integration, own bundles, text helpers, rspec integration...). I think it depends on the look and feel that you like.

Comment: two things are currently keeping me from switching from TM to ST2: the sidebar can only be on the left. and I really dislike the look of the search results.

Comment: You need to compare TextMate 2 with Sublime Text. By now TextMate 1.5 is too old.

Comment: @gdelfino Textmate 2 is under development alpha-release software. I'm not going to compare alpha-releases to production releases because I want a stable product to code on with.

Comment: @tom I understand. But keep in mind that if you decide to use Textmate 2, you can choose to use the nighty builds (less stable) or the normal releases (more stable).

Answer (score 1):

I come form Vim and try both TextMate 2 and Sublime Text 2 for a while. I like them both, but for different reasons.

I'm pretty sure you can make TextMate 2 act almost like Sublime Text 2 by plugins and setting, or vice versa. And they both have tons of gorgeous themes/plugins/snippets. So I just try to list the 'out of box' and potentials difference between them.

TM2:

1. Open source
2. Fine integrate with rails just out of box.
3. Switching between files with hotkey follow rails conventions.
4. Can move project list to the left.
5. Install plugin and adjust setting by GUI.
6. Run rails test in text editor out of box.
7. More build-in wrapping features.
8. Complete word by [esc] and add snippet by [Tab]

ST2:

1. Cross plateform
2. Ability to imitate some Vim behaviors.
3. Adjust setting by editing a json file. Less intuitive for GUI user, but can source control and transfer it easily.
4. Switching between files by Ctrl-P out of box.
5. Complete word and add snippet all by [Tab]
6. A 3rd party nice package manager.

Please correct me if any error or missing stuffs. And I think the best way is try them both for couple weeks, know the possibility and tune one of them upon your favorite work flow.

Comment: Thanks for the comparison. I was more interested in Textmate 1.5, the current stable release. Thanks for the good points nonetheless.